# Ng serve for angular application is not starting the server , it shows error

Tags: html, css, angular, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I start my server by writing `ng serve -o`, it shows an error:

> (Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled
> exception occurred: Script file
> node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js does not
> exist.)

Now, what should I do?

---

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

---

Above is my angular.json code.

Comment: Have you checked the given directory to see if the file really exists?

Comment: yes , I checked @Batajus

Comment: path looks wrong: /css/js/? i would think it would just be /js remove the css part

Comment: What if you just include a bootstrap script on your index.html file?

Comment: but why bother including every time @KibéM.C

Comment: yes, I think it helped me .... thanks a tonn @MarkHomer

Comment: aah.. there's only one index.html file in your Angular project